# Power function in C++

Tags: c++

I was playing with an implementation of a power function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int pow(int b, int e)
{
  int result;

  if (e == -1 && b != 0)
  {
    cout << "b = " << 1/b << endl;
    return 1/b;
  }

  else if (b != 0 && e != 0)
  {
    //int e_int(int (e));
    bool e_bool(e < 0);
    e = (e_bool*-e + !e_bool*e);
    result = b = pow(b, -e_bool)*(b*!e_bool + +e_bool);
    cout << endl << "\"result\" = " << result << " " << e << endl;

    for(int i = 1; i < e; i += 1)
    {
      result *= b;
    }
    return result;
  }

  else if (e != 0 && b == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  else if (e == 0 && b != 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  else if (b == 1)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  else if (e == 1)
  {
    return b;
  }

  else
  {
    cout << endl << "Error";
    return -1;
  }
}

int main ()
{
  cout << endl << pow(-2, -1);

  return 0;
}
```

The output [is](http://codepad.org/NMXX1Ejp):

```
b = 0

0
```

Why does b get set to 0?

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: What do you think 1/2 is?

Comment: OOps, rookie mistake. Thanks fellas.

Comment: Next time try to come up with a minimalistic example. Just too much noise here.

Comment: Human beings have brain to use for things like this, debugger should be used in more complex examples.

Comment: `::pow` is a reserved name.  You should probably use something else.

Comment: @NikolaNinkovic: that depends on your level. If you are still learning, your brain might just not be sufficiently trained.

Comment: @AndyProwl Well you are right, but using debugger is not going to improve it :)

Comment: @Nikola Funny. I found years ago that using a debugger sped up my understanding of how a given language worked without becoming a mindless crutch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer division can only produce integer results.  Your program causes this line:

```
cout << "b = " << 1/b << endl;
```

To run, and if `b` is any integer larger than 1, the result will be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

I would not say `b` gets set to 0. Inside your function you have this statement:

```
cout << "b = " << 1/b << endl;
```

Since `b` is an integer, `1/b` is *integer division* and the value is ends up being `0`.